# How Can i create a Table like this in Html. especially the First Row

Tags: html

[image: A Sample Image]

I got this sample from vertex42.com... and really need this in html format

Comment: Check this https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

Comment: that is awesome.. thanks Alot..

Comment: As a partial solution I got [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kubhcd1/). I’m not sure whether you need the text rotated or even rotated _and_ skewed as well. I also tried to minimize the width of the header cells in an easy way, but couldn’t figure it out yet.

Comment: Thanks,,.. but the above solution worked for me ... Thanks for the reply